# Is it possible inner classes in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
class demo {
    interface test {

    }
}
```

is it possible in Java innerclasses?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I exactly understand your question, but I think the answer is: Yes, a class can declare an inner interface.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, inner classes are possible in Java.

In your code it looks like you're talking about interfaces though. Having inner interfaces are possible, too:

```
public class Demo {
   public static interface Inner {

   }
}
```

You can declare inner classes, too:

```
public class Demo {
   private class Inner {

   }
}
```

Comment: i am asking is it possible interface write inside the class

Comment: hmmm, looks like I don't understand your question fully. Since the "static" is redundant in the above code and "package" is the default visibility, I think you should be fine, writing just "interface" ;) I hope this helps this time - if not: never mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically interface inside a class is correct .
But it depends upon your usage. Logically it will be correct depending upon your usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any enum, class, interface or annotation inside one another.

```
public interface A {
    public @interface B {
        public class C {
            public enum D {;
                public interface E {
                    // keep on going.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```